# GEE: Structure Insensitive Pigment Index time series for multiple polygons

Tags: google-earth-engine, modis, vegetation-index

I am trying to calculate the *Structure Insensitive Pigment Index* (**SIPI**) using `MOD13Q1.061 Terra Vegetation Indices 16-Day Global 250m`. More specifically, I would like to get a time series for multiple polygons in my shapefile. It took me so long to write this piece of code and it works fine when I use only one single band. Unfortunately, as soon as I try to combine the bands in an expression (or formula) to calculate the **SIPI**,  I keep getting all sorts of errors.

What am I doing wrong?

```
// import shapefile in GEE
// var table: Table users/xxxx/BadungSud
//////////////////////////////////////////
// Take  a shapefile with multiple IDs: BadungSud has 3 IDs (3 Kuta)
// will download a time series for every ID. One column per ID with rows as timestamps.

var theID="ID" /// variable that identify the ID in the shapefile
var MyFolder='forestLoop' /// The folder is created automatically
var desc1 = 'SIPIloop'; /// what I am downloading= name of the file

var StartDate='2001-02-02'
var EnDate= '2001-07-07' 


var ColeccionSentinel = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/061/MOD13Q1")
  .filterDate (StartDate ,EnDate);

var Vegetacion = ee.Image(ColeccionSentinel.mean());  
      // SIPI (Structure Insensitive Pigment Index)
var SIPI = Vegetacion.expression ('float ((NIR - BLUE) / (NIR - RED))',{
    'NIR': Vegetacion.select('sur_refl_b02'),
    'BLUE': Vegetacion.select('sur_refl_b03'), 
    'RED': Vegetacion.select('sur_refl_b01')});
                 
                 
var triplets = SIPI.map(function(image) {
  return image.reduceRegions({
    collection: table.select([theID]), 
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), 
    scale: 30
  }).filter(ee.Filter.neq('mean', null))
    .map(function(f) { 
      return f.set('imageId', image.id()).setGeometry(null);
    });
}).flatten();
print(triplets.first());
var format = function(table, rowId, colId) {
  var rows = table.distinct(rowId);

  var joined = ee.Join.saveAll('matches').apply({
    primary: rows, 
    secondary: table, 
    condition: ee.Filter.equals({
      leftField: rowId, 
      rightField: rowId
    })
  });

  return joined.map(function(row) {
      var values = ee.List(row.get('matches'))

        .map(function(feature) {
          feature = ee.Feature(feature);
          return [feature.get(colId), feature.get('mean')];
        });
      return row.select([rowId]).set(ee.Dictionary(values.flatten()));
    });
};



var table1 = format(triplets, 'imageId', theID);


Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: table1, 
  description: desc1, 
  folder:MyFolder,
  fileNamePrefix: desc1,
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your script it is not really clear what you are after, but your index computation on your mean image (`vegetacion`) should look like this:

```
var SIPI = ee.Image().expression({
  expression: 'float ((NIR - BLUE) / (NIR - RED))',
  map: {
    NIR: Vegetacion.select('sur_refl_b02'),
    BLUE: Vegetacion.select('sur_refl_b03'), 
    RED: Vegetacion.select('sur_refl_b01')
  }
}).rename('SIPI');
```

But after that you are trying to map over an image (your mean vegetacion variable), which is not possible. So if you want a SIPI index for each image you need to map over the image collection and create it seperately.

```
var sipiTimeseries = ColeccionSentinel.map(function(image){
  var index = ee.Image().expression({
  expression: 'float ((NIR - BLUE) / (NIR - RED))',
  map: {
    NIR: image.select('sur_refl_b02'),
    BLUE: image.select('sur_refl_b03'), 
    RED: image.select('sur_refl_b01')
  }
}).rename('SIPI');
```

Can't see if it works for you because your assets are not shared. But it should get you going.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/7c854af4cb620694fc2390396041435d